# How do I use TypeScript to pass parameter to Javascript that used arguments object

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I currently using Angular 8 and trying to use someone script. I encounter a problem and lack of knowledge regarding this problem.

In the javascript its function work like this,

```
window.X = function() {
    var e = argument.length > 0...
```

How do I pass values into this Javascript function in Typescript?

Comment: You mean something like this?: `window.X = (a, b) => { <code> };` Or I misunderstood something?

Comment: `function add(x: number, y: number): number {
  return x + y;
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle external functions in TypeScript with proper typing, simply declare it somewhere before you use it. In TypeScript variable parameter length is typed as `(...args: any[])` (or more strict typing in case the parameters all are of the same type).

Example:

```html
  <script>
    // function defined in index.html
    window.X = function() {
      console.log('X', arguments.length);
    }
  </script>
```

```js
// angular component
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

// declare external function with proper type
declare const X: (...args: any[]) => void;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  run(): void{
    // call the external function with multiple parameters
    X('a', 'b');
  }
}
```

Here's a working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zdr8ca?file=src%2Findex.html

Answer (score 0):

Every javaScript code is also valid TypeScript code. so your Function should run in Typescript as you mentioned it.

you can Pass values like in a normal Javascript function:

```
window.X = function(numberToAdd) {
    return numberToAdd + 5
}
```

TypeScript allows you to add Types to the passed Values and to the return value of the function. Adding a Type to a passed Value would look like this:

```
window.X = function(numberToAdd: number) {
    return numberToAdd + 5
}
```

Which would result in a Typescript error if you would try to pass a String to the function

Adding a return Type to the function would look like this:

```
window.X = function(numberToAdd): number {
    return numberToAdd + 5
}
```

Which would result in a error if you would try to access values that a number does not have like

```
X(5).length
```

Such Typescript errors allow you to see mistakes in your Code before running it and therefore can prevent lots of bugs.